# Reverse an array of chars and simultaneously store into separate array with for loops using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, reverse

> Blockquote

Note: i don't want to use built in libraries or functions of that other than "iostream" and 
    "string".

```
char wrd[26],rev[26];

int y,i,s;

s=strlen(wrd)-1;

for(y=0;y<s;y++) for(i=s;i>=0;i--)
{
    rev[y]=wrd[i];
}
```

> Blockquote

Below is the same done manually; it works, but you get random chars used to fill the rest          of the array< i need to know where and how to insert the /0 element:

```
{
char drw[26], wrd2[26];
int s,i=0;

s=strlen(wrd2)-1;

drw[0]=wrd2[s];
drw[1]=wrd2[s-1];
drw[2]=wrd2[s-2];
drw[3]=wrd2[s-3];
drw[4]=wrd2[s-4];
drw[5]=wrd2[s-5];
drw[6]=wrd2[s-6];
drw[7]=wrd2[s-7];
drw[8]=wrd2[s-8];
drw[9]=wrd2[s-9];
drw[10]=wrd2[s-10];
drw[11]=wrd2[s-11];
drw[12]=wrd2[s-12];
drw[13]=wrd2[s-13];
drw[14]=wrd2[s-14];
drw[15]=wrd2[s-15];
drw[16]=wrd2[s-16];
drw[17]=wrd2[s-17];
drw[18]=wrd2[s-18];
drw[19]=wrd2[s-19];
drw[20]=wrd2[s-20];
drw[21]=wrd2[s-21];
drw[22]=wrd2[s-22];
drw[23]=wrd2[s-23];
drw[24]=wrd2[s-24];
drw[25]=wrd2[s-25];

cout << drw;
}
```

Comment: You should only write one `for` instead of 2.

Comment: You should update your previous question with new information or make sure that this is distinctly a different question.

Comment: Can i delete one of my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups ! First version is bad because you put two loops to the result will not be what you expect : each char of rev will successively receive all the chars from wrd and end with `wrd[0]` !

This first version should be (with one single loop) :

```
s=strlen(wrd) - 1;

for(y=0;y<=s;y++)
{
    rev[y]=wrd[s - y];
}
rev[s + 1] = '\0'; /* don't forget to null terminate rev */
```

For second version, you should simply add

```
drw[s + 1] = '\0';
```

before the `cout` to correctly end the reversed word.